# WPF Set Out of the Box Property to Inheritable

Tags: wpf, xaml, inheritance, dependency-properties

Is it possible to change the inheritance settings for a WPF property? Ideally, I would set ToolTipService.ShowDelay at the Window or UserControl level and everything in the visual tree would inherit from there. I know this is possible with a custom dependency property, but with the default properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this directly because you're working with an attached property. With a normal DP you can override the metadata on a specific (usually derived) type, but there's not really a place you can do this for an attached property because the metadata is declared on the owner (`ToolTipService`) but it's used on every other type by referencing that owner, and also the metadata it originally declared.

You can simulate the behavior you want by declaring your own version of the property and then using that to set the real one on each inheritor of that value. Here's the property declaration:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InitialShowDelayProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "InitialShowDelay",
        typeof(int),
        typeof(MyWindow),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits, InitialShowDelayPropertyChanged));

    public static int GetInitialShowDelay(DependencyObject target)
    {
        return (int)target.GetValue(InitialShowDelayProperty);
    }

    public static void SetInitialShowDelay(DependencyObject target, int value)
    {
        target.SetValue(InitialShowDelayProperty, value);
    }

    private static void InitialShowDelayPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ToolTipService.SetInitialShowDelay(d, (int)e.NewValue);
    }
```

And then to set the inheriting value just set your new property and it should set ToolTipService's real one for you on all children:

```
local:MyWindow.InitialShowDelay="555"
```

Comment: I used your code but the property doesn't seem to be available. I created a new custom control library, created a new control and template, then added your property. The only change I made was to typeof(MyWindow) to match my control. When I try controls:FunctionPanel., InitialShowDisplay isn't available.

Comment: Ignore that last comment, I forgot to add the setters and getter. Thank you! This was a huge help.